# Highlight rows of a Netsuite transaction search

Tags: netsuite

I have a transaction search that give me a list of all the Sales order that are pending fulfillment. I would like to highlight the rows where all the items of the sales order are on hand (which mean the order is ready to be fulfilled). How can I do that ?

I tried the "Highlight if... (Summary)" with the following condition : Minimum of Formula (Text) does not contain No, with the following formula:

```
CASE WHEN {item.quantityonhand} >= {quantity} THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
```

But it doesn't work

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can get closer to what you are asking for if you think of something that works with the summary values, e.g., max, min, count or sum

The formula numeric column:
`case when ({quantity} - {quantityshiprecv}) > {item.quantityonhand}  then 1 else 0 end`

will have a 1 for lines that can't be fulfilled and 0 for lines that can't

so if you group on document number and sum the formula you will have a list of sales orders with number of lines that can't be fulfilled and can highlight on sum(formula) > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Saw a similar post on reddit few days ago so i'll post the response here aswell.

[Alternative way to highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuSzF.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Link-only answers are discouraged on SO, you should include relevant parts from the link in the answer itself. You can [learn more here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)